# How to bind a DataGridView to a List of Doubles

Tags: c#, winforms, list, data-binding

How can I bind a DataGridView to a List of Doubles?

What I did is:

```
    private List<double> x_axis_values = new List<double>();

    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = this.x_axis_values;
        this.dataGridViewX.DataSource = source;
    }
```

but when I update the list the DataGridView remains empty. Sorry, first day using DataGridView...

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<double> x_axis_values = new List<double>();
private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();;
    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
        bindingSource.DataSource =  this.x_axis_values.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();
        dataGridViewX.DataSource = bindingSource;        
    }
```

Comment: Thank but, it is not working for me. One column Value is created, but changes to the List still does not update the Grid, which remains empty at the form.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: The DataGridView and the x_axis_values are empty. When I add a double to the list:" x_axis_values.Add(x) " x must appear at the DataGridView.

Comment: Still not working. I was able to make it to show the right number of itens doing this:            " this.dataGridViewX.DataSource = null;
            this.dataGridViewX.DataSource = this.x_axis_values; " after adding some numbers to the list. It seems like it is not recognizing "Value" since double is not an object with a Value property.